# Handwriting to Text Conversion API's in IOS

Tags: ios

I would like to know any API for converting handwritten to text conversion in IOS(Objective C), or some sample code for conversion. I do not want to use any third party API, Can somebody share the code.

Thanks,
Leela

Answer (score 1):

There are no builtin handwriting recognition APIs in iOS. You'll have to use 3rd party code (or write your own).

Edit: Well, technically some of the iconographic keyboards perform basic character recognition, but there's certainly nothing for western languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I googled a lot and not able to get any sample code. Can you please atleast share some API which I can port and use.

Comment: Hi,Atleast can you plz let me know which 3rd party API's can be used in IOS?